# Swift method parameters, not always named?

Tags: swift

Trying to do a basic web view app for experimenting, I ran into the `loadRequest` method. Methods with swift accept the named parameters, however loadRequest does not. Just wondering on the reasoning for this? I found the inconsistency kind of odd.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://en.wikipedia.org")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters in standalone functions and instance methods in a class are handled differently. The Swift book has this to say about it:

> “Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter
>   name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names
>   both local and external parameter names by default. This convention
>   matches the typical naming and calling convention you will be familiar
>   with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for expressive method
>   calls without the need to qualify your parameter names.”

An example:

```
class Counter {
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes: Int) {
        count += amount * numberOfTimes
    }
}

var myCounter = Counter()
myCounter.incrementBy(3, numberOfTimes: 4)
println(myCounter.count)    // 12
```

Answer (score 1):

There are somewhat complicated rules around what the default behavior is for named parameters. However, they are all centered around the idea of making Swift method calls read the same way that Objective-C method calls are read. There are two types of names for each parameter: external and internal. External names are used when calling the function / method / initializer, and internal names are used only within the implementation of the function / method / initializer.

With initialization methods, the "initWith" is left off but otherwise it is the same. So --`-[NSURL initWithString:]` becomes `NSURL(string:)`.

> initializers do not have an identifying function name before their
>   parentheses in the way that functions and methods do. Therefore, the
>   names and types of an initializer’s parameters play a particularly
>   important role in identifying which initializer should be called.
>   Because of this, Swift provides an automatic external name for every
>   parameter in an initializer if you don’t provide an external name
>   yourself

All other methods are defaulted to not name the first parameter but name all of the following parameters.

> Swift gives the first parameter name in a method a local parameter
>   name by default, and gives the second and subsequent parameter names
>   both local and external parameter names by default. This convention
>   matches the typical naming and calling convention you will be familiar
>   with from writing Objective-C methods, and makes for expressive method
>   calls

Functional calls have a 3rd rule applied to them. They default to not have any external name.

> If you want users of your function to provide parameter names when
>   they call your function, define an external parameter name for each
>   parameter, in addition to the local parameter name. You write an
>   external parameter name before the local parameter name it supports